# IE8 write during a loop

Tags: javascript

My cgt prog on www.stonebanks.co.uk displays the output on Opera as the javascript program runs. IE8 appears to have stopped until all the calcs are done then displays the lot.

I added a textbox to show progress. It works fine with Opera (I don't need it there), but only writes the progress report when IE8 has finished. Is there any way to tell IE8 to write during a loop?

```
....
....
document.f.progress.value = "Company : " + company + " Record count = " + numrecds.toString(); 

 } // end of loop

document.f.progress.value = "Finished";
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Javascript is inherently single threaded - The only way I can think of to get it to update the UI while lopping would be to take the contents of the loop and put it inside a webworker. However I'm not sure that IE8 supports webworkers.

Can you maybe put the loop contents inside setTimeouts e.g. `setTimeout(function(myVariablesRequired) { //MyLoopCode }, 1);`